# Does it matter which vendor's JDK you build with?

Tags: java, build-process

If I'm deploying to servers with WebSphere 6.1 (Java 1.5), should I use IBM's JDK on my build box?  Or will Sun's JDK compile to the same binary?

If I should use IBM's, where can I get the Windows x64 version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would as much as possible try to keep development as close to production as possible.  Ibm and Sun's JDK's certainly both satisfy the SDK certification, but they are by no means identical.  Their instrumentation and memory management are at least slightly different.  If nothing else, the bugs in the JDK will be different, which your code may only trip over in one scenario vs. another.  It'll also probably only happen at 4 am, and when the moon is full especially when you have company over.

I can't tell you where to get IBM's jdk, but if you've got a license to websphere at your company, you should have a contact at IBM to get you a link to that JDK.

Good luck, and always try to minimize differences where possible.

Answer (score 4):

It should not make any difference. It will probably not be exactly the same binary but 100% compatible. I assume you're using external libraries anyways like log4j or maybe hibernate or whatever and those are not built using the IBM JDK.

There are differences in the JREs, however. For example, I remember that when I listed methods or fields of a class using reflection, the IBM JRE used to give them to me in a different order than the Sun one.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the same JDK to build that is going to be used when the application is deployed (if you have control over that).

The binaries may be different if the compiler is different, but they should be semantically identical. I don't know if IBM wrote its own compiler. The JRockit JDK actually uses the Sun compiler but the JVMs are different. So with JRockit the binaries are identical.

If the application is used with different JDKs at run time, I would still build with the one that you think will be used at deployment time most of the time and do some runtime testing with different JDKs.

Answer (score 3):

The IBM JDK ships with J9 VM and SUN JDK runs on Hotspot VM which have different algorithms to function. You application may not perform the same if you deploy and tune in SUN JDK and your production uses IBM JDK for WAS. Check with the vendors and open a ticket,let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

Compiling with any JDK should not cause a problem unless you are referencing classes outside of the java.* and javax.* pacakges (which you should not be.)  Of course there's always a chance that there's a discrepancy between a given vendor's JDK and the spec which could cause some really weird runtime errors that are hard to track down, but I've never seen this before in my experience.

I would recommend running any test suites you have using the target JRE as runtime behaviors differ between vendors much more often than compilation semantics do.

Answer (score 2):

JDKs are compiling your code to a **bytecode** and not directly to **machine code**. Is expected that compilers of different vendors generating cross-vendor compatible code. For example IBMs compiler for JDK1.5 will produce code that runs on SUN's JDK 1.5 and later without any problem.

Another issue is how compilers optimizing the bytecode, I have not information that some compilers performing better optimization than others. The largest part of optimization is performed during runtime by JVM (for example JIT (just-in-time) or AOT (ahead-of-time) strategies).

Answer (score 1):

Having worked with WebSphere a long time the version of the JDK is very important.  WebSphere 6.1 ships with an IBM JDK 1.5 (or is it 5).  When you patch the WebSphere there are equivalent patches for the JDK as well.  While it may work with a different version of the JDK (even a different vendor) I doubt you will get much support from IBM if something goes wrong.

If you need a 64 bit JVM I would suggest that there is probably a 64 bit build, while I cannot comment on windows specifically I can tell you there is a 64 bit WebSphere 6.1 build for both AIX and Linux.

The best answer is to check with the vendor and see if they will support your configuration.  What you don't want to do is get it working, then have an issue in live, call up support and find out that you have an unsupported environment.

Answer (score 0):

They should compile to the same bytecode specification, although they may compile different bytecode (much as in the same way different C compilers generate different machine code). I don't think there would be any problems in running the resulting code - I've compiled Java 1.4 on a Mac and then deployed to IBM's J9 running on a PocketPC before with no problems (this was before J9 could handle Java 5 bytecode).

Regardless, I'd definitely make your compilation platform a bullet point on your readme file so that your client can see if it is a problem.

Alternatively, you could build and deploy with ANT, and use Sun's JDK with ANT.