# Are there any issues if I compile with IBM JDK and run with Sun JRE

Tags: java

Are there any issues if I were to compile with IBM JDK and run with Sun JRE
Assuming we use the same major version of IBM and SUN

Comment: It is best practice to develop and deploy with the same JDK.  You can have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115184/does-it-matter-which-vendors-jdk-you-build-with) for more information about that.

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8941293/1079354

Answer (score 3):

DISCLAIMER: I'm focusing solely in your question:

> Are there any issues if I compile with IBM JDK and run with Sun JRE?

Short answer: no.

Explanation:

Yes, there are important differences between "IBM's Java" and "Oracle's Java", but in your case you are just generating bytecode (compiling) and that's one of the things that is strongly specified in the [JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/). So if the bytecode is correctly compiled then it should run in any JVM.

CAVEAT #1: I'm assuming that you are ONLY compiling java code with IBM's compiler, you are NOT compiling AND testing running IBM's java executable; if so then yes, you'll have issues, because the execution won't behave the same (one JVM could use more memory than the other, etc.) for more about this topic follow the links already provided by @ForguesR and @Makoto in their respective comments.

CAVEAT #2: It doesn't mean that IBM's compiler necessarily produces the same bytecode as the Oracle's one. It just means that both would produce proper bytecode to be executed in any JVM.

CAVEAT #3: I'm also assuming that the same libraries, dependencies, etc. are available by both the compiler AND  the JRE